# How to sort uniq values from a text file?

Tags: sort, uniq

I have a text file as shown below:

```
A f1
B f2
A f3
B f4
B f5
```

I want to sort it based on first column values and keep it in separate files.

Desired output:

A.txt:

```
A f1 
A f3
```

B.txt:

```
B f2
B f4
B f5
```

Tried it with `uniq` but it’s not working.
Edit: I am not able to post the desired way the txt file and output file should be, but it should one below in next lines

Comment: `uniq` only recognises **adjacent** duplicates. `sort -u` may be needed to recognise duplicates, for further processing...

Comment: Are there any dulicates in the input that you want to eliminate with `uniq`? If yes, please [edit] your question and extend your example input to show at least one duplicate (and if necessary adjust the expected output). In this case you could state that your question is not fully answered by the similar questions.

Answer (score 3):

In most cases, you can simply:

```
awk '{print > $1 ".txt"}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is awk and not uniq.

```
awk ' $1 == "A" { print }' $file > something.txt` #This will print all A's

awk ' $1 == "B" { print }' $file > something.txt` #This will print all B's.
```

Note: `$file` will be the name of your input log.

EDIT: My original answer was based on the data provided. I have now updated it. As such, my original "All you need is grep" is no longer valid and changed to "awk" instead.

Comment: @JyotiPal I have updated the solution to use awk instead

Answer (score 0):

A short awk script will do this job:

```bsh
sort file | awk '
  $1 != prev {prev = $1; if (out) close(out); out = $1 ".txt"}
  {print > out}
'
```

Adding the `close()` to prevent "too many open files" errors.